# Is question about optimisation of user interface on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have made a dialog box that hosts a lot of various controls (around 50) using C++ and raw WinAPI.

Although my application works, I still wish to somehow reduce the number of controls I use in a dialog box. I wish to ask on Stack Overflow for help, so I first wanted to check here if this type of question is on-topic.

If it isn't, can you suggest another SE network that could help me with this problem?

Comment: You could check the meta's of codereview.se or programmers.se but I doubt it will be very welcome on those sites. You risk asking for opinions...and that simply doesn't fit well anywhere.

Comment: 50 controls?  I hope I never have to configure your app:)

Comment: @MartinJames: I had to made database with a lot of tables/fields and that was my first try. That is why I need someone experienced to help me do this right...

Comment: What about [ux.SE]? Disclaimer: I'm not at home there, check their meta and on-topic please.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Posting this same question there as I type this... Thank you.

Comment: +1 for asking if a question would be on topic *before* actually posting it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thank you. I always had respect towards the community, and I know how hard everybody try to help. I also know the feeling of going through a crappy question so I do everything in my might to avoid asking such questions. Best regards.

Comment: This is what happens when the gist of what you teach programmers is how to make an inventory application in Java/C++/C# and throw them in the market as-is. **50** controls in a ***dialog box***.

Comment: Hmm, don't put every character in a separate static control? I can't think of any other way you could have that many controls in a single dialog box. Also, look into the ListView and similar complex controls that alleviate you from having to have a whole host of checkboxes, comboboxes, or whatever you've got now.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thank you for your advice. My problem is that I have a database with lost of fields and I need to have a GUI that enters their values. Listview allows to edit only first cell, and only via edit control. I might need a combobox in the first cell, edit control in second, checkbox in third... [I am trying to create a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895351/window-size-of-edit-control-combobox-is-not-properly-adjusted-when-using-movewin) but can't find the proper way at the moment... Can you try to help? Best regards.

Comment: You can write code to support inline editing of subitems in a ListView ([for example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6646/In-place-editing-of-ListView-subitems)). Basically, it involves detecting the user's request to edit, dynamically creating and displaying a TextBox on top of the ListView control at the appropriate position, and then using the value entered into the TextBox to update the subitem programmatically.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that this is Meta. Hmm, yeah. So that's a question you could ask on Stack Overflow. :-)

Comment: Isn't this *exactly* what [ux.se] is for?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I believe [Deduplicator suggested that out 8 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271492/is-question-about-optimisation-of-user-interface-on-topic#comment94785_271492), so yes? :)