# Are questions about usability and user interface on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, scope

I just saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295007/usability-problems-with-empty-tables). It's tagged with [usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usability) and [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) because it's asking about user interface design (in this case in [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) but it's pretty platform/language agnostic).

Questions about usability are not strictly about programming and they have their natural home in another StackExchange site: [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Should they be considered **off-topic when they're only about design** without a specific programming issue (as, for example, stated on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271492/is-question-about-optimisation-of-user-interface-on-topic))?

On the other side we have 790 questions tagged [usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usability) ([user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) is too generic to be considered on- or off-topic when used alone).

Are these questions on topic for StackOverflow or - in theory - they should all closed/deleted and/or migrated to UX? What we should do with newer questions? Is [usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usability) a red flag for possibly off-topic questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most new questions about usability and UX should be asked on [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com). However, the question could be on topic here if, for example, it's asking something along the lines of:

> I'm trying to implement *this* usability feature and I'm getting this error/behaviour.

as this is an implementation question which would be off topic over there. So while you might want to take a closer look at questions tagged [usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usability) the presence of the tag is not sufficient to indicate that the question should be migrated.

Any old* question **can't** be migrated, so if it's now off topic then it should be closed. However, I wouldn't go searching for them, but only vote to close if you came across them while looking for something else.

* old is defined as older than 60 days.